# Finding matches between identical MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

An application matches ladies to gentlemen according only to the ladies’ criteria. There are 2 identically structured MySQL tables. The qualities of individuals are recorded with Boolean values.

TABLE 1:  GentlemenQualities

ID / Handsome / Charming / Rich / Athletic / Fashionable

Peter / 1 / 1 / 1 / 0 / 0

George / 0 / 1 / 0 / 1 / 0

*Mary is looking for a Charming and Handsome gentleman*

TABLE2:  LadiesCriteria

ID / Handsome / Charming / Rich / Athletic / Fashionable

Mary / 1 / 1 / 0 / 0 / 0

*The following code finds a gentleman for Mary at the time that her new data is entered into the database:*

```
SELECT ID FROM GentlemenQualities WHERE Handsome = 1 AND Charming = 1
```

*We find Peter… We made a match! Peter was also rich, but that is not important to Mary.*

Peter's row is DELETED from GentlemenQualities, and Mary's row DELETED from LadiesCriteria

*Along comes Janice, she wants a fashionable gentleman, she doesn’t care about his other qualities*

Janice / 0 / 0 / 0 / 0 / 1

```
SELECT ID FROM GentlemenQualities WHERE Fashionable = 1
```

This draws a blank. Janice is not matched yet.

*Now there is a new entry in GentlemenQualities*

Hans / 1 / 0 / 1 / 0 / 1

**How do I match Hans to Janice as efficiently as possible? (there may be hundreds of unmatched ladies)**

I'm using php & MySQLi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Ladies criteria is equal or less the Gentlemen criteria, then you should insert the new Gentlemen data on the following SQL query:

With Hans:

```
SELECT ID FROM LadiesCriteria
WHERE Handsome <= 1
AND Charming <= 0
AND Rich <= 1
AND Athletic <= 0
AND Fashionable <= 1
```

You would find:

```
Janice | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
```

With Peter:

```
SELECT ID FROM LadiesCriteria
WHERE Handsome <= 1
AND Charming <= 1
AND Rich <= 1
AND Athletic <= 0
AND Fashionable <= 0
```

You would find:

```
Mary | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

But not Janice, because she wants a Fashionable gentlemen.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are using parsing of string with (|) pipe and string matching.

I recommend not to use string matching, this is performance error, instead use integer to to comparison. create a pattern of integer and then match with corresponding integer number.

Comment: This was just my way of formatting the question to separate the database columns and their values clearly - it's not code. As it is confusing, I will edit and use '/' instead.